# Интеграция paypal v2.0 в asp net core

Tags: asp.net-core, paypal, asp, paypal-api

Хей-хей,всем доброе время суток. есть маленькая проблема,  когда я посылаю с помощью этого куска кода :

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<string> ConfirmAsync()
    {
        var environment = new SandboxEnvironment("Acc2-UPp-z25_Olh73h5VZB3XjR16eUKtL2lHoIc27IJn8-2f5R8-Kish229pYjzdy18KR8khHJRQO5Q", "EIb_0hbZQPAEioCGLAzVpn87zRswB7zLAoRtda06Oc4IhrDAmtGYAI2z6xYplX6TdARnsuVh2TC3tHNM");
        var client = new PayPalHttpClient(environment);
        var payment = new Payment()
        {
            Intent = "sale",

            Transactions = GetTransactionsList(),
            RedirectUrls = GetReturnUrls(baseurl, "sale"),
            Payer = new Payer()
            {
                PaymentMethod = "paypal"
            }
        };

        PaymentCreateRequest request = new PaymentCreateRequest();
        request.RequestBody(payment);

        try
        {
            HttpResponse response = await client.Execute(request);
            var statusCode = response.StatusCode;
            Payment result = response.Result<Payment>();
            return statusCode.ToString();
        }
        catch (HttpException httpException)
        {
            var statusCode = httpException.StatusCode;
            var debugId = httpException.Headers.GetValues("PayPal-Debug-Id").FirstOrDefault();
            return debugId;
        }

    }
```

Здесь получаю список транзакций :

```
var transactionList = new List<Transaction>();

        transactionList.Add(new Transaction()
        { 
            Description = "Transaction description.",
            Amount = new Amount()
            {
                Currency = "USD",
                Total = "100.00",       // Total must be equal to sum of shipping, tax and subtotal.
                Details = new AmountDetails() // Details: Let's you specify details of a payment amount.
                {
                    Tax = "15",
                    Shipping = "10",
                    Subtotal = "75"
                }
            },
            ItemList = new ItemList()
            {
                Items = new List<Item>()
        {
            new Item()
            {
                Name = "Item Name",
                Currency = "USD",
                Price = "15",
                Quantity = "5",
                Sku = "sku"
            }
        }
            },
        });

        return transactionList;
```

То в разделе API call  на сайте paypal ,я имею желтые треугольники, при этом я не знаю, как понять даже в чем проблема, ибо к примеру status code каким-то образом словно закодирован, подскажите в чем проблема и как можно решить.

Comment: Прикольно, примеры кода бесполезны. Надо смотреть какие заголовки передаются на палку и какие от нее приходят. Так-же на самом сайте есть некое подобие консоли, где видны все транзакции и ошибки, интерфейс там старый.

Comment: @Profesor08, ну пример, я выслал тем, кто уже возможно работал с paypal v2.0 , ну и соответственно с asp net core 2.0  на что она больше и ориентирована,по этому думаю тому, кто работал  с ним , то куски, не бесполезны. Оно проходит успешно, ( Call Api показывает, что успешно, если не указывать без товаров, может быть я не правильно, что-то делаю, но думаю, чтобы создать платежку, надо и список товаров и возможно даже номер счета, или я не прав?

Comment: Это оно? https://paypal.github.io/PayPal-NET-SDK/

Comment: Смотрю там даже ничего изобретать не надо.

Comment: @Profesor08 ,это тот SDK, но версия не та, в второй много что сменили, а предыдущая не совсем подходит к dotnet Core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в указании доставки, так как я указал Shipping = "10", но не указал, кто будет забирать, где и контактные номера, убрав это -  платежка создалась.

В общем : полная отправка будет выглядеть так:

```
  var environment = new SandboxEnvironment(ваш ключ, секрет от песочницы\реального счета(в реальном надо реальную среду выбирать));
        var client = new PayPalHttpClient(environment);
        var payment = new Payment()
        {
            Intent = "sale",
            Transactions = new List<Transaction>()
            {
                new Transaction()
                {
                    Amount = new Amount()
                    {
                  Total = "100.00",
                   Currency = "USD",
                  Details = new AmountDetails()
                {
                   Tax = "25",
                    Subtotal = "75"
                }
                    },
                    ItemList = new ItemList()
                    {
                        Items = new List<Item>()
                        {
                             new Item()
                             {
                                 Name="SonyHeadPhones",
                                 Currency = "USD",
                                 Price = "15",
                                 Quantity = "5",
                                 Sku = "Sku",
                                 Tax  = "25",
                                 Description = "ITS ITEM!!!!!"
                             }
                        }

                    }, Description = "JustSimplePayment",
                }
            },
            RedirectUrls = new RedirectUrls()
            {
                CancelUrl = "линк сайта, который обрабатывает отмену",
                ReturnUrl = "линк сайта,который принимает оплату"
            },
            Payer = new Payer()
            {

                PaymentMethod = "paypal"
            },

        };

        PaymentCreateRequest request = new PaymentCreateRequest();
        request.RequestBody(payment);


        try
        {
            HttpResponse response = await client.Execute(request);
            var statusCode = response.StatusCode;
            Payment result = response.Result<Payment>();
            LinkDescriptionObject approvalLink = PaypalHelpers.findApprovalLink(result.Links); - генерим с помощью хелпера линк для подтверждения оплаты.
            return approvalLink.Href.ToString();
        }
        catch (HttpException httpException)
        {
            var statusCode = httpException.StatusCode;
            var debugId = httpException.Headers.GetValues("PayPal-Debug-Id").FirstOrDefault();
            return debugId;
        }
```

сам хелпер :

```
 public static LinkDescriptionObject findApprovalLink(List<LinkDescriptionObject> links)
        {
    foreach (var link in links)
            {
                if (link.Rel.Equals("approval_url"))
                {
                    return link;
                }
            }
            return null;
}
```

Подтверждение платежки на стороне вашего сервера :

```
  public async Task<string> Execute(string paymentId,string PayerId)
    {
        var environment = new SandboxEnvironment(ваш ключ, секрет от песочницы\реального счета(в реальном надо реальную среду выбирать));
        var client = new PayPalHttpClient(environment);
        PaymentExecuteRequest request = new PaymentExecuteRequest(paymentId);
        request.RequestBody(new PaymentExecution()
        {
            PayerId = PayerId
        });
        try
        {
            HttpResponse response = await client.Execute(request);
            var statusCode = response.StatusCode;
            Payment result = response.Result<Payment>();
            return result.Id;
        }
        catch (HttpException httpException)
        {
            var statusCode = httpException.StatusCode;
            var debugId = httpException.Headers.GetValues("PayPal-Debug-Id").FirstOrDefault();
            return debugId;
        }
```